# Battery Menu Bar doesn't show Time Remaining

Tags: macos, power-management

Kinda a unique issue here I haven't been able to find the solution to on Google.  As you can see in the screenshot below, my battery menu doesn't give me time remaining on Battery.  Not even System Preferences gives me it.

[image]

[image]

Has this happened to anyone else? I'd love to re-enable it.  If it's important, I'm running macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several failures to cause that, but let's rule out the obvious.

Open terminal.app and type:

```
pmset -g pslog
```

The log will show what the power management subsystem is seeing from the SMC. After trying to connect power, disconnect power and seeing charge for 10 minutes and then off charge for 10 minutes, you should have a good understanding of what is or what isn't working.

At that point, try resetting your SMC one time. Make a note of the information as if that doesn't fix things it's likely a hardware service situation.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 - How to reset the SMC

Comment: So, I ran this for the least 2 days.  It does give me estimated time remaining. I get `-InternalBattery-0 (id=3211363) 54%; discharging; 2:06 remaining present: true`.  So it seems the SMC is returning the time remaining.  I've tried resetting the SMC more times than I can count for this issue to no avail.

Comment: If one SMC reset doesn't work, then you have faulty hardware and need a repair or that isn't the cause. Are you saying that no matter what - the battery shows 54% or do the numbers go up and down in at the command line, just not in the GUI? @tokan_one

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, this was actually an intentional change as of macOS 10.12.2.  Likely in response to the complaints about short/erratic battery life in the newer Touch Bar-equipped models of MacBook Pro, Apple simply removed that information from the menu.  It is, however, still accessible from the Energy tab of Activity Monitor.

From [this page](https://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/12/macos-10-12-2-includes-graphics-fixes-for-the-new-macbook-pros-and-more/):

> Apple tells us that according to all its testing and user data, the batteries in the new MacBook Pros are performing normally—there’s no bug that’s sapping your battery, and your real-world battery life is still going to be influenced strongly by your workload. The only battery life-related fix in 10.12.2 is the removal of the “time remaining” estimate from the operating system. Apple says this is because modern components switch power states so frequently and quickly that it’s hard to correctly estimate remaining battery life based on current activity.

Answer (score 1):

I made a really simple little app that displays the remaining time in the mac menubar.
https://github.com/funkyremi/macos-battery-remaining-menubar

Answer (score 0):

The battery time remaining was intentionally removed by Apple due to the inaccuracy of the estimation, which is highly dependent on the laptop workload. Nonetheless, there are some free mac os apps, such as [TLOB](https://itunes.apple.com/app/tlob-time-left-on-battery/id1229885630?l=en&mt=12), that bring this feature back.